# Testing non-fatal error messages with boost c++ unit test suite

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I have a function that prints an error message to stdout when it encounters a certain condition.

```
if(!condition)
    printf("ERROR: Condition fail!");
```

The unit test for this function is picking up the "ERROR" keyword, and while all the assertions pass, the boost unit test suite considers it an error in execution and displays it. Is there a way to specify an expected error message, or expected error string for a given unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The unit test for this function is picking up the "ERROR" keyword,

It is not.

> and while all the assertions pass, the boost unit test suite considers it an error in execution and displays it

Not at all. The unit test is unaware of the fact that your test prints to the console.

Your test, though, contains a line of code:

```
printf("ERROR: Condition fail!");
```

That line has the immediate effect of printing the following text to the standard output device:

```
ERROR: Condition fail!
```

This is the only reason you're seeing the text. If you inspect the report or log you'll find that (unless asserts failed) the test passed.